# Select from database a specific JSON node using Rails/AREL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, arel

Pretend I have a table called `books` and it has a `json` type column called `misc` where some miscellaneous data has been saved. Using Rails/AREL I would like to extract just `id` and the number of pages (`num_pages`) from all the books.

In `psql` I can do the following:

```
SELECT id, misc->'num_pages' FROM books ;
  id   |   ?column?    
-------+---------------
 23562 | "220"
 22188 | "355"
```

(Note: the above query produces the same results with `-->` as with `->`).

I expected this to work:

```
pry> Book.select("id, misc->>'num_pages'")
  Book Load(1.7ms)  SELECT  id, etc-->'num_pages' FROM "books"
  Book Load(1.5ms)  SELECT  id, etc-->'num_pages' FROM "books"
=> #<Book::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3ff7e934d8f4>

pry> Book.select("id, misc->'num_pages'")
  Book Load(1.1ms)  SELECT  id, etc->'num_pages' FROM "books"
=> [#<Book:0x00007fefd3c11a68 id: 23562>, #<Book:0x00007fefd3c116a8 id: 22188>]
```

...when I remove the `->'num_pages'` part, it returns the entire `misc` field (so I know it's *almost* working):

```
pry> Book.select("id, misc")
  Book Load(0.9ms)  SELECT  id, etc FROM "books"
=> [#<Book:0x00007fefe4e99fb8
  id: 23562,
  etc:
   {"num_pages"=>"220",
...
```

Comment: What did you get when you ran your two Rails ARELs? Error message? Nil?

Comment: I updated the question to show you :)

Comment: Does my answer work? I'm not sure why pluck works over select.

Comment: It works - thank you. I added the deprecation warning I saw and the resolution that it conveniently suggests. I am still curious to see this solved with `select`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't get it done with `.select` but `.pluck` works in this form:

```
Book.pluck("id", "misc -> 'num_pages'")
  => [[23562, "220"], [22188,"355"]]
```

However, this will produce a deprecation warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used 
as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s): "misc->'num_pages'". 
Non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.0. This method should
not be called with user-provided values, such as request parameters or model
attributes. Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql().
```

So use `Arel.sql()` as suggested:

```
Book.pluck("id", Arel.sql("misc -> 'num_pages'"))
  => [[23562, "220"], [22188,"355"]]
```

Comment: @user664833, What version are you using. I'm on Rails 5.1.7

Comment: I'm on `Rails 5.2.3`.